# can't get my page to extend to the bottom of the viewport

Tags: html, css

i'm getting extremely frustrated here. i can't seem to get my centered column to extend all the way to the bottom of the page. i tried clearing floats, and i tried messing with the height of the body and html and columns, but it's not working.

i'd really appreciate it if someone could take a look and tell me what's going on. i just can't seem to figure it out, and this isn't the first time i've had this problem. i don't understand what's happending.

http://www.thefittedshirtchicago.com/tfs.html

if you scroll to the bottom, below the icons, there is a little bit of space where the lighter background shows through. i can't seem to get that to go away. the black of the center container is supposed to extend down behind it. it's especially evident if you change the size of your window.

any tips would be very helpful.

Comment: Maybe try setting height:auto; on centerContainer. Should work if all the elements within are set to position:relative;

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have the following after the (clear-div that follows the) footer-div:

```
<br />
c
```

Try removing that!

Comment: sorry, that was a desperate attempt to make my container stretch to the bottom. it's gone now, but the problem persists.

Comment: @patricko No problems in my browsers; Opera 12, Internet Explorer 8 and Chrome. Have you refreshed and still problems?

Comment: if you make the window smaller height-wise, then scroll down, you can see that the container isn't filling all the way.

Comment: @patricko Sorry, I can't reproduce the error you describe after you removed the `<br /> c`, even though I have a low window and scroll to the bottom. In my browsers, the bottom icon-container fills all the way down.